# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

i am always facing this error when i try to integrate andengine.jar and e3roid.jar within own android apps.
please help me.

```
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.e3roid.examples/com.e3roid.examples.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.e3roid.examples.SplashScreenActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.e3roid.examples-1.apk]
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.e3roid.examples.SplashScreenActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.e3roid.examples-1.apk]
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-12 15:53:13.667: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you declared the Activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is specific to e3roid.

Check "Order and Export" of your project E3roidExamples.

Java Build Path --> Order and Export.

**e3roid.jar might be "unchecked"**

Please check it & run again on device.

it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

this problem is occurs when you don't declare the activity in manifest file with proper name. But some time it happens just because your java file is not fall in to proper package that you are referencing..

just see your splash screen package name and delete once and check if it gives any error .. if dont then problem is because of that)... again place it and clean the project and run...

and also your splashscreen class should be public